# ARC-Authentication-Results permerror sending email from c#

Tags: .net, email

I'm trying to send payslips out to all our staff but a bunch of gmail accounts are having the email delayed or blocked.

I have tested with a GSuite account and I receive the email, but in the "original email" view of the email, I see the following lines:

```
 ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
 spf=permerror (google.com: permanent error in processing during lookup
 of no-reply@our-domain.com.au: mail.optusnet.com.au not found)
 smtp.mailfrom=no-reply@our-domain.com.au
```

and

```
 Received-SPF: permerror (google.com: permanent error in processing during
 lookup of no-reply@our-domain.com.au: mail.optusnet.com.au not found)
 client-ip=000.000.00.000;
```

We have a valid SPF record to allow sending emails from our server through O365.

Here is the class that I'm using to send the emails out.  I'm using a Parallel.ForEach loop to send the emails out.  With max threads of 3 or 4 in production.

```
public class EmailService : IDisposable
{
    public const string DefaultFromAddress = "no-reply@our-domain.com.au";
    private const string Office365Host = "smtp.office365.com";
    private const int Office365Port = 587;
    private const string Office365UserName = "O365_App_UserName";
    private const string Office365Password = @"--Password--";

    //private readonly SmtpClient _smtpClient;
    private SmtpClient _smtpClient;
    private readonly Logger _logger;

    public EmailService()
    {
        _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        _smtpClient = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = Office365Host,
            Port = Office365Port,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Office365UserName, Office365Password),
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            EnableSsl = true,
            TargetName = "STARTTLS/smtp.office365.com"
        };
    }

    public bool SendEmail(MailMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            _smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex, $"Failed to send email: from: {message.From.Address}, to:{message.To.First()}. more details:{ex.InnerException}");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _smtpClient.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Here is the code in the loop that sends the composed messages:

```
using (EmailService emailService = new EmailService())
{
  employee.EmailSent = emailService.SendEmail(mailMessage);
}
```

What am I missing here?
Do we need to do something with SPF records for mail.optusnet.com.au as well?

Any other suggestions will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.  Turns out after digging and testing, there was nothing wrong with my code, it was to do with the DNS records.  The SPF type records have been superseded by the TXT type records.  Google seems to be more secure and was checking for the SPF type, failing on each domain listed in that entry.  As I removed them from the record, a new domain appeared.  We then removed the SPF type completely and the error went away.